# SCP using ganymed / Java - no such file or directory?

Tags: java, scp

I am trying to SCP a file from a Windows server (with openSSH / Cygwin installed) to a Mac using Java's Ganymed.  I get the path to my current directory programmatically, but for some reason it's saying the local directory isn't found.  It is absolutely the correct path, so I don't know what's going on.

```
Connection conn;
String hostname = "10.10.1.2";
String username = "myuser";
String password = "mypass";

String localDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String remoteFile = "/path/to/the/file.txt";

Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
conn.connect();
conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);
SCPClient scp = conn.createSCPClient();
scp.put(remoteFile, 2815, localDir, "0644");
conn.close();
```

Because I am using the .getProperty method, I know the path is right. Also, I have separate methods which ssh to the windows machine and start/stop a service, so I know the credentials are right.  So why does this not work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I gather this code runs on the Mac, and it's supposed to copy a file from the Windows system to the mac?

```
scp.put(remoteFile, 2815, localDir, "0644");
```

The [`put()`](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/SCPClient.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) operation transfers a file from the local system to the remote system. You want to call [`get()`](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/SCPClient.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), which transfers a file from the remote system to the local system. Replace the put() line with something like this:

```
scp.get(remoteFile, localDir);
```

Comment: First of all - thanks!  No idea how I missed that.  I still had problems, though, and it turns out the reason is because the [documentation](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/) refers to an older version than the [current version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.ethz.ganymed/ganymed-ssh2/262).  I switched to version `build210` in my pom.xml and was able to use ganymed as written with no issues.

(Adding this for anyone's future reference)

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/RemoteSSH/commit/1b07e9e503a3d991c513a5069afc69179208bfee the scp.put I tried but lacking real info on how to use it I ended up using SFTPv3Client which is also provided as part of the changes hudson have done on build260